# Почему не контент не двигает футер?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, flexbox

При добавлении в дочерний блок "left_top" блока "main" текста, сама текст выходит за футер, а должен двигать его. почему иак происходит?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background: #7df799;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#left {
  background: #bcaff4;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#left_top {
  
}

#left_bottom {
  
}

#content{
  flex: 1 1;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
  background: #7df799;
}
```

```html
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TESTIK</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header>header</header>
      <main class="clearfix">
        <div id="left">
          <div id="left_top">left_top</div>
          <div id="left_bottom">left_bottom</div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">content</div>
      </main>
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно ли такое сделать без флекс-боксов, а при помощи позиционирования?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> main {
>   ...
>   flex: 1 1;
>   ...
> }
> ```

Потому что это позволяет сжимать его до 0.

Поменяй на

```
flex: 0 0 auto;
```

Comment: Поменял, футер не прижимается к низу экрана ,если нет контента

Comment: @РоманФридман, `1 0 auto`?